# how can i programatically establish upper and lower bounds for cv2 mask from kmeans data

Tags: python, image-processing, k-means, opencv

I am working on separating a simple image into a new set of images where each image contains only one colour from the original. to figure out which rgb colours to separate out I have used k means. The  centroids of the clusters give ne a set of rgb colours, and converting to cv2 bgr colourspace allows me to  mask out those colours. but this demands and upper and lower bound for the colours. concerned.
I am confused because I cannot figure out how to establish the upper and lower bounds from the data.
lastly , I am trying to programmatic mimic "by color select" like in gimp, if there is a better way that I am missing please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    upper_bound_list = []
    lower_bound_list = []
    dict = {i: data[np.where(values[1].flatten() == i)] for i in range
            (0, k)}

    for key, value in dict.items():
        n = (value[:, 0].max(), value[:, 1].max(), value[:, 2].max())
        upper_bound_list.append(n)
        n = (value[:, 0].min(), value[:, 1].min(), value[:, 2].min())
        lower_bound_list.append(n)

    for i in range(0, len(upper_bound_list)):

        lower = np.array(lower_bound_list[i], dtype="uint8")
        upper = np.array(upper_bound_list[i], dtype="uint8")
        mask = cv.inRange(img, lower, upper)
        output = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```